# How to interact with multiple webelments in testcafe using json file

Tags: json, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to interact with multiple elements like multiple checkboxes radio buttons, buttons etc. I want to store the label/name of the elements into the json file. How can I interact with multiple elements using the name from Json file in testcafe

Comment: Since you didn't share any code, perhaps just a general piece of advice would work for you. You load the json file, you read the keys/values and you use them in e.g. selectors to access those elements in the DOM. If you have a concrete problem with your code, please share it so we can focus on something more particular.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have not written the code but I want to manage webelements specially checkboxes those provide multiple choices, in somecases radio buttons  and submit buttons (single button allows to perform multiple actions by changing name e.g "First Click" then same button will be displayed as "Second Click" and so on) I want to retrieve the name of the elements from the json file 
{
"buttons":["First Click", "Second Click"],
"Checkbox":["Choice1", "Choice2"]
}
where First click, second click and Choice1 and Choice2 are the name of webelements, hope this will help

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [data-driven test example](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/create-data-driven-tests). It shows how to load data from a JSON file. You can use the loaded data in Selector expressions like `Selector('button').withText(data.buttons[0])` to reference elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your particular use case, but speaking purely technically, you can easily do what you're asking:

**Resources/names.json**:

```json
{
    "buttons": [
        "First Click", 
        "Second Click"
    ],
    "checkboxes": [
        "Choice1",
        "Choice2"
    ]
}
```

then I can lod the file in a test file and work with the values:

```js
import { getBaseUrl } from '../Helpers/baseUrl';
import { getEnv } from '../Helpers/env';
import Webelements from '../Objects/webelements'

const baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
const env = getEnv();

const webelements = require('../Resources/names.json');

fixture `Webelements`    
    .page(baseUrl);   

test              
    ('Access Webelements From Json', async t => {
        
        webelements.buttons.forEach((button) => {
            console.log(button);
        });

        webelements.checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
            console.log(checkbox)
        });
});
```

this will print the following into the console:

```
First Click
Second Click
Choice1
Choice2
```

Another solution could be using classes:

**Objects/webelements.js**:

```js
class Checkboxes {
    constructor () {
        this.choices = {
            1: "Choice1",
            2: "Choice2"
        }
    }
}

class Buttons {
    constructor () {
        this.names = ["First Click", "Second Click"]
    }
}


class Webelements {
    constructor () {        
        this.checkboxes = new Checkboxes();
        this.buttons = new Buttons();
    }      
}

export default new Webelements();
```

and use it like this:

```js
test             
    ('Access Webelements From Classes', async t => {
        
        Object.entries(Webelements.checkboxes.choices).forEach(([key, val]) => {
            console.log(key + " - " + val);
        })

        Webelements.buttons.names.forEach((name) => {
            console.log(name)
        });
});
```

this will output:

```
1 - Choice1
2 - Choice2
First Click
Second Click
```

So, there're options, but the point is that some solutions are better for some situations. I have very little idea about your situation, so you have to make this decision for yourself.